# Matrix and multiplication complexity

Tags: math, matrix, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity of the solution to a problem.

> Let X, Y and Z be n × n matrices. Suppose we want to verify whether XY = Z. What is the complexity of solving the problem directly by computing XY?

The correct answer is O(n<sup>3</sup>), but I don't understand why. Why is this the case?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication about complexity. Your assumption is not correct.

Comment: Try writing a function that multiplies two matrices. Count how many scalar mulitiplications are performed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithm for computing the product of two n × n matrices is to use the fact that the entry at position (i, j) in the product is the inner product of the ith row of the first matrix and the jth column of the second matrix. Computing the inner product of this row and this column takes time Θ(n), because there are n entries that need to be pairwise multiplied and summed together. Therefore, each entry of the resulting matrix takes time Θ(n). Since there are n<sup>2</sup> total entries in the matrices, the total time complexity using the naive algorithm is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

There are faster matrix multiplication approaches than the one described here that use more sophisticated algorithms. You might want to look up the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm or the Strassen algorithm, which are asymptotically faster than the naive algorithm.

However, there are better randomized algorithms for checking whether the product is correct. Check out [Frievalds' algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm) for an O(n<sup>2</sup>)-time randomized algorithm that with high probability can detect if the multiplication is correct.

Hope this helps!